# Executing 1 million commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have 6 million setblock/fill commands in store (mostly for setting command blocks/repeaters) that I would like to execute in my world, so as to cover 36 chunks. Mcfunctions are not very efficient as they can only execute 65536 commands meaning I would have to organize 120 50k command functions. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: could you use a datapack? also note that that many command blocks might accidentally chunkban.

Comment: @Topcode that only happens in servers